How do I remove the maps review-box
Is there a way top stop the review-box element from displaying over a map? I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

How are you displaying your map?  What "review-box element"?  Please provide more details on your issue, preferably with a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Here's the page.
https://www.greatglenhostel.com/location.php
I want to get rid of the review bit at the top left, or even the whole top left panel.
The Google api produces all of the code in the Iframe that encloses the map. I know that the div that encloses the review wording is called "review-box" by right clicking over it in firefox and using "inspect" to open the console.

Live links to broken pages don't help future readers on the context of your question.  Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve] in the question itself, not a link to an external site that demonstrates the issue.

I disagree. It's a straightforward question. And it's not a broken page. Thanks for nothing.

If its not doing what you want, it is "broken", and once you fix it, it will no longer demonstrate the issue.

Answer from Google: from the API POV it is not possible to remove just the reviews. The entire panel can be removed if you call the map in "view" mode rather than "place" mode, but then you also lose the marker. Will have to see if there is a JS or css workaround
